# Using Array of ids vs join table Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am creating a Laravel Application with Eloquent connected to MySQL DBMS where I have three models:

- **Product**
- **ProductGallery**
- **File**

I have also the following relations

- One **Product** has one **ProductGallery**
- One **ProductGallery** has many **File**

My question is:
Is it okay if I store images in **ProductGallery** as an array of file_ids
instead of creating a join table or having gallery_id in **File** model?

```
    public function setImagesAttribute($images)
    {
        $this->attributes['images'] = serialize($images);
    }

    public function getImagesAttribute()
    {
        if (empty($this->attributes['images']) || is_null($this->attributes['images'])) return [];

        return unserialize($this->attributes['images']);
    }
```

I am asking this question to know if there is any side effects for this method
and in the future there might be other models related to **File** model (Category may have featured image file and so on).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Better Option is creating a pivot table.. Because further when you have to join , you pull the array and you have to execute a query under a loop that is bad..

Comment: I will use File::find() on the array [find accepts array of ids] also